# How to add ssl certificate to .Net core Project with Kestrel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssl, kestrel-http-server

I'm trying to add an ssl certificate to .net core project with Kestral.
I have tried to configure ssl certificate pfx file path and the password on appsettings.json file, this solution worked for me but I want to store the password on a vault so I have tried to set the cert path and password on the CreateHostBuilder method using

```
webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options => {               
            var port = 5002;
            var pfxFilePath = @"path\certificate.pfx";
            var pfxPassword = "pass"; 

            options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, port, listenOptions => {
               
                listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
   
                listenOptions.UseHttps(pfxFilePath, pfxPassword);
            });
        });
```

but I got ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error message.

Comment: Are you trying the right port?

Comment: Certificate has to be loading in both client and server.  See following to load certifcate in server : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0#sni-with-servercertificateselector

Comment: You can get the password by calling your `key-vault` then pass the value to your password instead of passing the `local password`